# Android Fragment Google Maps V2: Error inflating class

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm developing an app which uses fragment tab, one of my fragment uses Google Maps V2 "`SupportMapFragment`"

```
public class A extends Fragment {
   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) 
   {
    View view = null;
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.all_coffee_shops_view, container, false);
    map = ((SupportMapFragment) getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
   }
}
```

my xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
   android:id="@+id/map_container"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent">

   <fragment
     android:id="@+id/map"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" 
   />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I'm calling B Fragment from this A fragment(A->B) and when I come back from B->, A fragment `onCreateView` throws an exception, "android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #132: Error inflating class fragment"

Comment: Check my answer on SO at this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19353255/how-to-put-google-maps-v2-on-a-fragment-using-viewpager/19354359#19354359

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    Log.d(TAG, "onDestroyView");

    Fragment f = getActivity()
            .getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    if (f != null) {
        getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction().remove(f).commit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

when once map `fragment` is created and when comes back to this fragment again fragment is `onCreateView()` is called that's why you are getting force close

Try this once in your fragment containing map

```
@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();

    Fragment f = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    if (f != null) 
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(f).commit();
}
```

please comment me about the result

Comment: Hey NARESH REDDY, Thanks for answering me question... since i'm using fragment tabs i'm using a base container for handle the view hierarchy in tabs, you code didn't work, but i used getSupportFragmentManager for getFragmentManager, then it worked like a charm...