# Replace a fragment in FragmentTabHost

Tags: android, android-fragments

I've implemented few `Fragments` in a `FragmentTabHost`, using:

Inside FragmentActivity Class:

```
FragmentTabHost mTabHost;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.e(TAG, "onCreateView()");

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    mTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);

    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("audio").setIndicator("Audio"),
            AudioFragment.class, null);
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("video").setIndicator("Video"),
            VideoFragment.class, null);

    mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);
}
```

In one of the `fragment` say `AudioFragment` there is a `button` which is supposed to open a new fragment over the current fragment of AudioFragment.

Inside AudioFragment.class

```
@Override
public void onClick(View button) {
    switch (button.getId()) {
    case R.id.bOpenNewFragment:

        // WHAT TO CODE, TO REPLACE THE CURRENT FRAGMENT OF AudioFragment 

        break;
    }

}
```

I *tried* the usual code using:

```
Fragment fragment = new ShowAudioDetailsFragment();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.realtabcontent, fragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```

But, it was creating problems when I switched to another tabs (*like state was not maintained & view of new fragment was merging with the layout of other tabs*).

**So How can I replace the fragment with the fragment opened within FragmentTabHost**

**Thank You**

Comment: Remove all views from parent view before replacing.

Comment: Check this answer by here at SO : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19353255/how-to-put-google-maps-v2-on-a-fragment-using-viewpager/19354359#19354747

Answer (score 0):

Just add this line

```
((RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.realtabcontent)).removeAllViews(); // whatever layout you have
```

before :

```
transaction.replace(R.id.realtabcontent, fragment);
```

Comment: tried inside my `onclick()` inside `Fragment` class, not working: `((LinearLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.realtabcontent)).removeAllViews();`

Comment: Sorry my bad, was getting class cast exception. Was using framelayout

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39715/discussion-between-rani-and-raul8)