# Replace getMap with getMapAsync

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I want to replace the deprecated `getMap` Method with `getMapAsync`, but I didn't use `MapFragment` but `GoogleMap` like this:

```
private GoogleMap googleMap;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

    try {
        if(googleMap == null) {
            googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        }
        googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        googleMap.setTrafficEnabled(true);
        googleMap.setIndoorEnabled(true);
        googleMap.setBuildingsEnabled(true);
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
```

If I replace the `googleMap` with `MapFragment` like this I'm not able anymore to `setMapType` and so on. So how can I change to `getMapAsync` in my case?

```
MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
```

Answer (score 62, accepted):

as in the official doc, get map async requires a callback;
it's there your "main entry point" for google maps stuff!

```
public class MapPane extends Activity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.map_activity);

        MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
        // DO WHATEVER YOU WANT WITH GOOGLEMAP
        map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        map.setTrafficEnabled(true);
        map.setIndoorEnabled(true);
        map.setBuildingsEnabled(true);
        map.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 36):

Very simple, just have your Activity implement the `OnMapReadyCallback` interface, and then assign your `googleMap` reference in the `onMapReady()` callback.

Then, perform any actions on `googleMap` that you want.

Here is a simple example:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap googleMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {

        googleMap = map;

        setUpMap();

    }

    public void setUpMap(){

        googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        googleMap.setTrafficEnabled(true);
        googleMap.setIndoorEnabled(true);
        googleMap.setBuildingsEnabled(true);
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use MapFragment you can still use stMapType method. Implement OnMapReadyCallback on your activity.
Create MapFragment and call getAsyncMap method on that object.
It will ask you to inplement onMapReady(GoogleMap map) method there you can set map type and so on. 
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The better way I found to understand the use of getMapAsync was to create a new project in Android Studio and use the template of google maps activity instead of an empty activity.

You will have a project that works to study and adapt your owns.