# getMap() is deprecated

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview

I have an application which required a Two different layouts in one recyclerview. I already done that. The first layout is for map.I am using mapview for that. And the second one is the lists of places.

My problem is the `getMap();` is deprecated.Is there any option I could use?

They said if I want to have inside a fragment, I should use mapview.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="160dp"
          android:orientation="vertical">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/mapHolder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        >
        <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
            android:id="@+id/mapImageView"
            xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            map:liteMode="false"
            map:mapType="normal"
            map:cameraZoom="15" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

```
 if (position == 0) {
                MyGoogleMap myGoogleMap = (MyGoogleMap) holder;
                GoogleMap googleMap = myGoogleMap.map.getMap();
                if (googleMap != null) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < mModelNearbies.size(); i++) {
                        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
                        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(mModelNearbies.get(i).getShop_lat()), Double.parseDouble(mModelNearbies.get(i).getShop_long()));
                        markerOptions.position(latLng);
                        markerOptions.title(mModelNearbies.get(i).getShop_name() + " : " + mModelNearbies.get(i).getShop_address());
                        googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
                    }
                }
            }
```

And for the OnMapReadyCallback.

```
class MyGoogleMap extends MyNearbyHolder implements OnMapReadyCallback {
        GoogleMap gMap;
        MapView map;

        public MyGoogleMap(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            map = (MapView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.mapImageView);

            if (map != null) {
                map.onCreate(null);
                map.onResume();
                map.getMapAsync(this);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
            MapsInitializer.initialize(mContext);
            this.gMap = googleMap;
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                this.gMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                LatLng latLng = new LatLng(14.5500, 121.0300);
                this.gMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
                this.gMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(12));

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Your Actual Problem :**

You already have `GoogleMap` object in your Holder class:

```
class MyGoogleMap extends MyNearbyHolder implements OnMapReadyCallback {

     // See this 
     GoogleMap gMap;

    //Your code 
}
```

Then why you are doing `myGoogleMap.map.getMap()` ??? **Just use the existing object on GoogleMap** like below :

```
if (position == 0) {
        MyGoogleMap myGoogleMap = (MyGoogleMap) holder;
        GoogleMap googleMap = myGoogleMap.gMap;
        if (googleMap != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < mModelNearbies.size(); i++) {
                MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
                LatLng latLng = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(mModelNearbies.get(i).getShop_lat()), Double.parseDouble(mModelNearbies.get(i).getShop_long()));
                markerOptions.position(latLng);
                markerOptions.title(mModelNearbies.get(i).getShop_name() + " : " + mModelNearbies.get(i).getShop_address());
                googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
            }
        }
    }
```

> Taking about replacing deprecated `getMap()`. You have already done
>   that. by using `map.getMapAsync(this);` in your Holder class. Because
>   `getMapAsync` is the replacement of `getMap`.

See this question for more info : [Replace getMap with getMapAsync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31371865/replace-getmap-with-getmapasync)

Comment: I get back to you after I tried it. 
Having a problem with my genymotion google map. Thanks

Comment: have you checked it ?? @CharlesGalvez

Comment: Sorry about that. Im checking on it.

Comment: Its not working. 
My if statement is inside the onBindViewHolder.

Comment: Its now working. I put my code inside OnMapReady.
How to simplify this? 
 MyGoogleMap myGoogleMap = (MyGoogleMap) holder;
I only put that inside my if statement in bondholder