# Build not working anymore with build tools 24

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-gradle-2.0

I have a quite complex project with several dependencies. Unfortunately the build does not work anymore since I updated to the latest build tool version.

I'm getting lots of errors because appcompat and maps dependency is not found anymore...

This is the gradle file of my application:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'


defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 9
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 578
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-project.txt'
        debuggable false
    }

    debug {


        debuggable true
    }
}
productFlavors {
    free {
        applicationId "com.sourcecastle.freelogbook"
        versionName "5.7.8 free"
    }
    pro {
        applicationId "com.sourcecastle.logbook"
        versionName "5.7.8"
    }

    register {
        applicationId "com.stefanzankl.triptracker"
        versionName "6.0"
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile project(':fuelTrackerLib')
compile project(':azure')
compile project(':obdii')
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'

}
```

This is the first "sub" library called fueltracker:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 9
    targetSdkVersion 24
}


}

dependencies {

compile project(':carBase')


}
```

this is the second "sub" library called carBase

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 9
    targetSdkVersion 24
}

}

dependencies {



compile project(':commons')

}
```

this is the third and last "sub" library called commons. All common libraries like Maps or Analytics are added here.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 9
    targetSdkVersion 24
}
}


dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0'

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.2.0'
compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.7'
compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:4.48'
compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-core:4.48'

compile project(':ambilWarna')
compile project(':excel')
compile project(':pdfjet')
compile project(':volley')

}
```

all my libs are registered in my settings.gradle file which looks like:

```
include ':comsourcecastlelogbook'

include ':fuelTrackerLib'
project(':fuelTrackerLib').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../myLibs/fuelTrackerLib')

include ':carBase'
project(':carBase').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../myLibs/carBase')


include ':commons'
project(':commons').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../myLibs/commons')





include ':ambilWarna'
project(':ambilWarna').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../myLibs/ambilWarna')

include ':volley'
project(':volley').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../myLibs/volley')





include ':azure'
project(':azure').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../myLibs/azure')


include ':excel'
project(':excel').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../myLibs/excel')

include ':pdfjet'
project(':pdfjet').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../myLibs/pdfjet')




include ':obdii'
project(':obdii').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../myLibs/obdii')
```

[image: SDK Manager]

[image: Android Studio SDK Manager]

Here the output:

Information:Gradle tasks [:ambilWarna:generateDebugSources, :ambilWarna:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :ambilWarna:mockableAndroidJar, :ambilWarna:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :azure:generateDebugSources, :azure:mockableAndroidJar, :azure:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :azure:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :carBase:generateDebugSources, :carBase:mockableAndroidJar, :carBase:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :carBase:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :commons:generateDebugSources, :commons:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :commons:mockableAndroidJar, :commons:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :comsourcecastlelogbook:generateProDebugSources, :comsourcecastlelogbook:generateProDebugAndroidTestSources, :comsourcecastlelogbook:mockableAndroidJar, :comsourcecastlelogbook:prepareProDebugUnitTestDependencies, :excel:generateDebugSources, :excel:mockableAndroidJar, :excel:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :excel:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :fuelTrackerLib:generateDebugSources, :fuelTrackerLib:mockableAndroidJar, :fuelTrackerLib:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :fuelTrackerLib:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :obdii:generateDebugSources, :obdii:mockableAndroidJar, :obdii:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :obdii:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :pdfjet:generateDebugSources, :pdfjet:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :pdfjet:mockableAndroidJar, :pdfjet:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :volley:generateDebugSources, :volley:mockableAndroidJar, :volley:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :volley:generateDebugAndroidTestSources]
:ambilWarna:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:ambilWarna:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:ambilWarna:checkDebugManifest
:ambilWarna:prepareDebugDependencies
:ambilWarna:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:ambilWarna:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:ambilWarna:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:ambilWarna:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:ambilWarna:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:ambilWarna:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:ambilWarna:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:ambilWarna:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:ambilWarna:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:ambilWarna:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:ambilWarna:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:ambilWarna:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:ambilWarna:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:ambilWarna:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:ambilWarna:prepareDebugAndroidTestDependencies
:ambilWarna:compileDebugAndroidTestAidl UP-TO-DATE
:ambilWarna:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:ambilWarna:compileLint
:ambilWarna:copyDebugLint UP-TO-DATE
:ambilWarna:mergeDebugProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:ambilWarna:packageDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:ambilWarna:incrementalDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard UP-TO-DATE
:ambilWarna:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:ambilWarna:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:ambilWarna:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:ambilWarna:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:ambilWarna:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
:ambilWarna:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:ambilWarna:transformNative_libsWithSyncJniLibsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:ambilWarna:bundleDebug UP-TO-DATE
:ambilWarna:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:ambilWarna:assembleDebug UP-TO-DATE
:ambilWarna:processDebugAndroidTestManifest UP-TO-DATE
:ambilWarna:compileDebugAndroidTestRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:ambilWarna:generateDebugAndroidTestBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:ambilWarna:mergeDebugAndroidTestShaders UP-TO-DATE
:ambilWarna:compileDebugAndroidTestShaders UP-TO-DATE
:ambilWarna:generateDebugAndroidTestAssets UP-TO-DATE
:ambilWarna:mergeDebugAndroidTestAssets UP-TO-DATE
:ambilWarna:generateDebugAndroidTestResValues UP-TO-DATE
:ambilWarna:generateDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:ambilWarna:mergeDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:ambilWarna:processDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:ambilWarna:generateDebugAndroidTestSources UP-TO-DATE
:ambilWarna:mockableAndroidJar UP-TO-DATE
:ambilWarna:preDebugUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:ambilWarna:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies
:azure:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:azure:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:azure:checkDebugManifest
:azure:prepareDebugDependencies
:azure:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:azure:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:azure:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:azure:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:azure:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:azure:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:azure:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:azure:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:azure:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:azure:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:azure:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:azure:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:azure:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:azure:mockableAndroidJar UP-TO-DATE
:azure:preDebugUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:azure:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies
:azure:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:azure:prepareDebugAndroidTestDependencies
:azure:compileDebugAndroidTestAidl UP-TO-DATE
:azure:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:azure:compileLint
:azure:copyDebugLint UP-TO-DATE
:azure:mergeDebugProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:azure:packageDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:azure:incrementalDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard UP-TO-DATE
:azure:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:azure:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:azure:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:azure:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:azure:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
:azure:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:azure:transformNative_libsWithSyncJniLibsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:azure:bundleDebug UP-TO-DATE
:azure:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:azure:assembleDebug UP-TO-DATE
:azure:processDebugAndroidTestManifest UP-TO-DATE
:azure:compileDebugAndroidTestRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:azure:generateDebugAndroidTestBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:azure:mergeDebugAndroidTestShaders UP-TO-DATE
:azure:compileDebugAndroidTestShaders UP-TO-DATE
:azure:generateDebugAndroidTestAssets UP-TO-DATE
:azure:mergeDebugAndroidTestAssets UP-TO-DATE
:azure:generateDebugAndroidTestResValues UP-TO-DATE
:azure:generateDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:azure:mergeDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:azure:processDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:azure:generateDebugAndroidTestSources UP-TO-DATE
:carBase:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:carBase:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:carBase:checkDebugManifest
:ambilWarna:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:ambilWarna:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:ambilWarna:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
:ambilWarna:mergeReleaseProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:ambilWarna:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:ambilWarna:checkReleaseManifest
:ambilWarna:prepareReleaseDependencies
:ambilWarna:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:ambilWarna:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:ambilWarna:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:ambilWarna:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:ambilWarna:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:ambilWarna:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:ambilWarna:mergeReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
:ambilWarna:compileReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
:ambilWarna:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:ambilWarna:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:ambilWarna:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:ambilWarna:processReleaseResources
:ambilWarna:generateReleaseSources
:ambilWarna:incrementalReleaseJavaCompilationSafeguard UP-TO-DATE
:ambilWarna:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:ambilWarna:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:ambilWarna:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:ambilWarna:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:ambilWarna:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
:ambilWarna:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:ambilWarna:transformNative_libsWithSyncJniLibsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:ambilWarna:bundleRelease UP-TO-DATE
:carBase:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:carBase:preDebugUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:carBase:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:carBase:preReleaseUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:commons:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:commons:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:commons:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:commons:compileLint
:commons:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
:commons:checkReleaseManifest
:commons:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:commons:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:commons:preDebugUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:commons:preReleaseUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:excel:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:excel:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:excel:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:excel:compileLint
:excel:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
:excel:mergeReleaseProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:excel:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:excel:checkReleaseManifest
:excel:prepareReleaseDependencies
:excel:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:excel:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:excel:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:excel:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:excel:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:excel:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:excel:mergeReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
:excel:compileReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
:excel:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:excel:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:excel:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:excel:processReleaseResources
:excel:generateReleaseSources
:excel:incrementalReleaseJavaCompilationSafeguard UP-TO-DATE
:excel:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:excel:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:excel:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:excel:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:excel:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
:excel:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:excel:transformNative_libsWithSyncJniLibsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:excel:bundleRelease UP-TO-DATE
:pdfjet:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:pdfjet:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:pdfjet:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:pdfjet:compileLint
:pdfjet:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
:pdfjet:mergeReleaseProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:pdfjet:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:pdfjet:checkReleaseManifest
:pdfjet:prepareReleaseDependencies
:pdfjet:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:pdfjet:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:pdfjet:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:pdfjet:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:pdfjet:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:pdfjet:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:pdfjet:mergeReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
:pdfjet:compileReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
:pdfjet:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:pdfjet:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:pdfjet:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:pdfjet:processReleaseResources
:pdfjet:generateReleaseSources
:pdfjet:incrementalReleaseJavaCompilationSafeguard UP-TO-DATE
:pdfjet:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:pdfjet:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:pdfjet:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:pdfjet:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:pdfjet:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
:pdfjet:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:pdfjet:transformNative_libsWithSyncJniLibsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:pdfjet:bundleRelease UP-TO-DATE
:volley:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:volley:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:volley:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:volley:compileLint
:volley:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
:volley:mergeReleaseProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:volley:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:volley:checkReleaseManifest
:volley:prepareReleaseDependencies
:volley:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:volley:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:volley:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:volley:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:volley:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:volley:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:volley:mergeReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
:volley:compileReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
:volley:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:volley:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:volley:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:volley:processReleaseResources
:volley:generateReleaseSources
:volley:incrementalReleaseJavaCompilationSafeguard UP-TO-DATE
:volley:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:volley:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:volley:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:volley:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:volley:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
:volley:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:volley:transformNative_libsWithSyncJniLibsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:volley:bundleRelease UP-TO-DATE
:commons:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2400Library UP-TO-DATE
:commons:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72400Library UP-TO-DATE
:commons:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2400Library UP-TO-DATE
:commons:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72400Library UP-TO-DATE
:commons:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42400Library UP-TO-DATE
:commons:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2400Library UP-TO-DATE
:commons:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAds920Library UP-TO-DATE
:commons:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAdsLite920Library UP-TO-DATE
:commons:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAnalytics920Library UP-TO-DATE
:commons:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAnalyticsImpl920Library UP-TO-DATE
:commons:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase920Library UP-TO-DATE
:commons:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement920Library UP-TO-DATE
:commons:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesClearcut920Library UP-TO-DATE
:commons:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGass920Library UP-TO-DATE
:commons:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMaps920Library UP-TO-DATE
:commons:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesTasks920Library UP-TO-DATE
:commons:prepareLogBookProAmbilWarnaUnspecifiedLibrary UP-TO-DATE
:commons:prepareLogBookProExcelUnspecifiedLibrary UP-TO-DATE
:commons:prepareLogBookProPdfjetUnspecifiedLibrary UP-TO-DATE
:commons:prepareLogBookProVolleyUnspecifiedLibrary UP-TO-DATE
:commons:prepareReleaseDependencies
:commons:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:commons:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:commons:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:commons:mergeReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
:commons:compileReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
:commons:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:commons:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:commons:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:commons:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:commons:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:commons:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:commons:processReleaseResources
:commons:generateReleaseSources
:commons:incrementalReleaseJavaCompilationSafeguard UP-TO-DATE
:commons:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
:commons:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac - is not incremental (e.g. outputs have changed, no previous execution, etc.).
C:\Users\Stefan\AndroidStudioProjects\myLibs\commons\src\main\java\com\sourcecastle\commons\activity\TimeMapActivity.java
Error:(41, 25) error: cannot find symbol method getMap()
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\Users\Stefan\AndroidStudioProjects\myLibs\commons\src\main\java\com\sourcecastle\commons\net\requests\AutorizedJsonRequest.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
:commons:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':commons:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
>   Information:BUILD FAILED
>   Information:Total time: 3.907 secs
>   Information:2 errors
>   Information:0 warnings
>   Information:See complete output in console

Comment: JDK ? 1.8 should it be. And JAVA_PATH ? Checked ?

Comment: In "Project Structure" under JDK Location I have: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65

Comment: and if it not helps, post your error log...  for a start only the first error

Comment: Error log only says: Error:(41, 25) error: cannot find symbol method getMap()

Comment: Try to make a [mcve] of your problem

Comment: @StephanBranczyk I'm sorry, but I can't find "show all packages". At the bottom of the SDK Manager I only see: Update/New, Installed, Obolete

Comment: @cricket_007 Build is working for simpler projects so I guess the problem is related to the complexity

Comment: @StephanBranczyk: I added a screenshot from my SDK Manager. Could you please have a look at it?

Comment: In the SDK Manager, I usually deselect all, then select all updates. Then check additional things to install, if needed. Anyways, what is that getMap error from?

Comment: The getMap() is caused because SupportMapFragment is not found which is located in: com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.2.0

Comment: Actually, in the Android Studio sdk manager, "Show package details" is what I had clicked on, and I have the Build-Tools 21.1.2 installed, plus the Android SDK tools 24.0.0, plus the Android SDK Build-Tools 24-rc4 (that I should probably remove). So may be, I didn't have the same problem as you did. Your sdk manager looks fine to me (although it looks slightly different than mine).

Comment: @StephanBranczyk: I added a screenshot from Android Studio's build in SDK Manager. Could please have a look at it?

Comment: Sorry. Your sdk manager looks fine. You could try removing the obsolete package, but I doubt that's the problem. Have you tried replacing getMap() http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31371865/replace-getmap-with-getmapasync Can you run a brand new "Hello World" project? If the answer is yes, you may want to add each dependency one by one to the gradle file of that "Hello World" project until something breaks.

Comment: It is definately not the getMap() since all my Activities are also red because AppCombat is not found. It is also no problem with my machine or my installation since a project with no libraries compiles. I will try to add the same references there... Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The new versions of play-services aren't working for me and my project. Don't know why?!

After I changed it back to version 8.3 erverything was working fine again...

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.3.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.3.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.3.0'
```

9.0.2 is also working

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.0.2'
```

This is not working!!

```
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.2.0'
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.2.0'
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.2.0'
```