# Cannot resolve method getMap()

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am trying to get a map fragment working within my application and I continue to get an error when trying to get my GoogleMap object.

> FragmentWithMap.java

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;



public class FragmentWithMap extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {
    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;
    private static final double LAT = 32.084;
    private static final double LON = 34.8878;
    Place place;
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private View view;
    private Marker marker;
    int userIcon = FragmentWithDetails.userIcon;

    public static FragmentWithMap newInstance(Place place) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        if (place != null) {
            args.putInt("id", place.getId());
            args.putString("name", place.getName());
            args.putString("address", place.getAddress());
            args.putFloat("lat", place.getLat());
            args.putFloat("lng", place.getLng());
        }
        FragmentWithMap fragment = new FragmentWithMap();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public FragmentWithMap() {
        //empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null && getArguments().getString("name") != null) {
            place = new Place(getArguments().getInt("id"), getArguments().getString("name"),
                    getArguments().getString("address"), getArguments().getFloat("lat"),
                    getArguments().getFloat("lng"));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (view == null) {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_with_map, container, false);
        }
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        android.support.v4.app.Fragment f = getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.fragmnet_container_map);
        if (f != null) {
            try {
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(f).commit();
            } catch (IllegalStateException ise) {
                Log.d("FragmentWithMap", "Already closed");
            }
        }

        ViewGroup parentViewGroup = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
        if (parentViewGroup != null) {
            parentViewGroup.removeAllViews();
        }
    }

    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    public void showPlace(Place place) {
        setPlace(place);
        setUpMap();
    }

    public void setPlace(Place place) {
        this.place = place;
    }


    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }

    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        // Do a null check
        if (mMap == null) {
            // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.


            Fragment mmm = getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_map2);
            mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) mmm).getMap();

            // Check if we were successful
            if (mMap != null) {
                setUpMap();
            }
        }
    }

    private void setUpMap() {
        double lat = LAT;
        double lng = LON;
        String name = "You are here";
        if (place != null) {
            lat = place.getLat();
            lng = place.getLng();
            name = place.getName();
        }
        if (marker != null) {
            marker.remove();
        }
        LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng);
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().
                position(position).
                title(name).
                icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(userIcon)).
                snippet("Your last recorded location");

        marker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(position, 15);
        mMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
    }

}
```

And here's the XML

> fragment_with_map.xml

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_map2"
    tools:context="com.example.eldad.myplacesapp.FragmentWithMap"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    />
```

I copied the code from a different app, where the method getMap() is merely deprecated, so I doubt the problem is in the code itself. I have no issue with it being deprecated, and I prefer not to use the getMapAsync() if I don't have to. But here for some reason I recieve the error

> "Cannot resolve method 'getMap()'"

. I also recieve an error

> "Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>
> > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details."

Though I can't be sure if it's connected to this issue.

Comment: Sounds like you're either missing the google maps library, or there is a version mismatch between the app you copied the code from and this app. Are the imports greyed out or showing an error in your IDE? Also, the second error is a direct result of the first error: the compile task failed, because of the compilation errors.

Comment: The imports were initially greyed, but I took care of it by copying the relevant library files and adding dependensie. Thanks for the clarification regarding the second error.

Answer (score 29):

The `getMap()` method was previously deprecated, and now it's been removed.  If you look at the [documentation for SupportMapFragment](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/SupportMapFragment), it's not there.

You can also see in the [release notes](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/releases):

> The previously-deprecated getMap() function is no longer available in
>   the Google Play services SDK. (It is still available in the Google
>   Play services APK that is delivered to Android devices.) The getMap()
>   function has been deprecated since December 2014. See the [release blog
>   post](http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com/2016/06/marker-zindex-and-more-come-to-google.html) for help with converting from getMap() to getMapAsync().

And from the blog post:

> In December 2014 we deprecated getMap() in favor of getMapAsync().
>   From this release onwards, you'll need to use getMapAsync() in order
>   to compile your apps.

So, just use getMapAsync(), it's simple.

First have your Fragment implement the OnMapReadyCallback interface:

```
public class FragmentWithMap extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment
          implements OnMapReadyCallback {
```

Then, modify your setUpMapIfNeeded() code, and add the onMapReady() callback:

```
private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
  if (mMap == null) {
    SupportMapFragment mapFrag = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_map2);
    mapFrag.getMapAsync(this);
  }
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    setUpMap();
}
```

Comment: So that worked in getting rid of that error, thanks! Now just to tkae care of the new error that inevitably cropped up...

Comment: I think this answer of yours is better. :-) Thanks anyways. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31371865/replace-getmap-with-getmapasync#answer-31371953

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0'


 map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                R.id.map)).getMap();
```