# Hi. In my activity appears this : Cannot resolve method getMap();

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity

*Here is the link of my activity, in wich appears thet error: cannot resolve method getMap();
I hope that you guys can help me on solve it. Thank you*

---

why when i put this appears public on red ?

```
        public class AddPostActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.add_post_activity);

            MapFragment fm = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.maps_fragment);
            fm.getMapAsync(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

            map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
            mUiSettings = map.getUiSettings();

            mUiSettings.setCompassEnabled(true);
            mUiSettings.setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
        }
    }
```

Comment: In the future, please put the code *in the question*, not via a link to an external site.

Comment: Try to localize the error and post your efforts and the relevant section of your sourse code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot resolve method 'getMap()'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38232747/cannot-resolve-method-getmap)

Comment: @DanielNugent can u see my other question under this question i have added the getMapAsync but appears public on read line, i have added this pubblic class into my initial pubblic class

Answer (score 1):

`SupportMapFragment` no longer supports `getMap()`. Please [use `getMapAsync()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/SupportMapFragment.html#getMapAsync(com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback)).

Note that the same holds true for `MapFragment` -- `getMap()` has been removed from the SDK.

Comment: How can i chane that

Comment: @MenjeHer: Replace `getMap()` with `getMapAsync()`. Provide [an `OnMapReadyCallback`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/OnMapReadyCallback) as a parameter to `getMapAsync()`. Move your code that starts using the `GoogleMap` into `onMapReady()` of the `OnMapReadyCallback`.

Comment: why appears public on read line ?