# cannot resolve getMap() or replace with getMapAsync()

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm new to android programming and have been struggling with this problem for a while. I read that getMap() has been deprecated and replaced by getMapAsync()
However, I cannot seem to find a way of using getMayAsync() because it uses the a fragment resource and i did not require a fragment resource for the map till now.

Here is my code:

```
public class RunMapFragment extends SupportMapFragment {
    private static final String ARG_RUN_ID = "RUN_ID";
    private GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
    public static RunMapFragment newInstance(long runId) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putLong(ARG_RUN_ID, runId);
        RunMapFragment rf = new RunMapFragment();
        rf.setArguments(args);
        return rf;
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = super.onCreateView(inflater, parent, savedInstanceState);
        mGoogleMap = getMap(); //Error here
        mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        return v;
    }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.
Is it possible to rollback the map API minimum sdk to verison 9 where getMap() can be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `getMap()` method [was deprecated and then removed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38234004/4409409), so you'll need to use `getMapAsync()` instead.

There is no need to override `onCreateView()` when the Fragment extends SupportMapFragment directly.

Instead, just call `getMapAsync()` from the `onResume()` override, and use the Google Map reference that is returned in the `onMapReady()` override:

```
public class RunMapFragment extends SupportMapFragment {
    private static final String ARG_RUN_ID = "RUN_ID";
    private GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
    public static RunMapFragment newInstance(long runId) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putLong(ARG_RUN_ID, runId);
        RunMapFragment rf = new RunMapFragment();
        rf.setArguments(args);
        return rf;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (mGoogleMap == null) {
            getMapAsync(this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mGoogleMap = googleMap;
        mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

Note that if you are targeting api-23 or higher, you'll need to ensure that the user has approved the location permission at runtime before using the `setMyLocationEnabled()` method, for more info see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41754169/4409409).