# The getMap () method does not work?

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I have yet another problem, :(
I saw in some tutorials that we have to use the getMap () method of the calsse SupportMapFragment to retrieve the reference of the map object.
The problem is that I do not find this method in the SupportMapFragment object (Android studio does not know this method)
is there another way to get my goal ? thank u guys ^^
[image]

Comment: Perhaps they removed it. They certainly have been pushing developers to use `getMapAsync()` for a couple of years.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `supportMapFragment.getMapAsync(OnMapReadyCallback)`.

Relevant documentation link [here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/SupportMapFragment.html#getMapAsync(com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback)).

Answer (score 0):

You have to use getMapAsync in the new version.
If you look at the documentation, getMap is no longer available:
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/SupportMapFragment

The getMapAsync is nothing difficult or boring to use, here you are a snippet:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/31371950/4120431