# How do I make my project compatible with getMapAsync?

Tags: android, google-maps

I had working code before updating my SDK *today*(for future reference look at the question asked date). `.getMap` used to give warnings that it was deprecated but now it is not even recognized as valid input. I am assuming this has happened because of the new release of API 24(Android Nougat). Without further ado here's the code:

```
private boolean initMap() {
        if (mMap == null) {
            MapFragment mapFrag =
                    (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            mMap = mapFrag.getMapAsync();
        }
        return (mMap != null);
    }
```

If anyone could help me to make changes to integrate `.getMapAsync()` I would really appreciate it.

Thank you!

UPDATE: Here's the new and updated code after looking at suggestions in answers(this is NOT in the onCreate)-

```
private boolean initMap() {
        if (mMap == null) {
            MapFragment mapFrag = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            mapFrag.getMapAsync(this);
        }
            return (mMap != null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        if (googleMap != null) {
            mMap = googleMap;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?  Can you refer to the documentation and try it, and see what happens?

Comment: @nasch I have tried to add `(GoogleMaps googlemaps)` in the empty parenthesis, but it didn't work.

Comment: Why did you do that?  The documentation says to pass in an `OnMapReadyCallback`, not a `GoogleMap`.

Comment: @nasch I admittedly followed a SO answer, rather than the official documentation(which I have browsed through).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace getMap with getMapAsync](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31371865/replace-getmap-with-getmapasync)

Answer (score 1):

What you need:

1.`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.2.0'` in your gradle file (latest maps lib), if you can't use it you might need to download the latest tools.

2.The activity that loads the map fragment has to implement `OnMapReadyCallback`. (This is the easiest way, you can create a different class that implements `OnMapReadyCallback`).

3.In the activity `onCreate` method, you need to do the following:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    /// additiona code here
    MapFragment mapFrag = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFrag.getMapAsync(this); //this is instance of your activity.
    //maybe code here
}

//callback method from OnMapReadyCallback
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    if (googleMap != null) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        //now the map is loaded, you can use it
    }
}
```

**EDIT AFTER CODE EDIT ON SO POST**

Your `initMap` is wrong, it can't return a `boolean` value because the `getMapAsync` is as the name says, async, that means the method will be executed and it will return immediately, not waiting for completion, so the `return (mMap != null);` will almost always return `false`. You should use `onMapReady` to check if the map is loaded or not.

Comment: Thanks for answering! Please look at updated code :D

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't get you. I have to put the "if map null" stuff in `onMapReady` if I got you correctly. If that is the case, please spoon feed me a give me the exact code because I don't understand how to do that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to call like this

```
    mapFrag = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFrag.getMapAsync(this);
```

and make your actifity (for instance) implement OnMapReadyCallback.
Then override call back method onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)

Comment: looks like I posted my answer moment latter )))

Comment: Thanks for answering! Please look at updated code :D