# I want to replace a Marker from a map when user visits that location ( gets near a Marker )

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

First, I plot a `Marker` like this:

```
public void addMarker(String title,String  lat,String Lng,int id,String address,int f)
{    
        marker= mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().snippet(title)
                .title(title+", "+address)
                .position(new LatLng(Double.valueOf(lat), Double.valueOf(Lng)))
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(id)));

        LatLng coordinate = new LatLng(Double.valueOf(lat), Double.valueOf(Lng));
        CameraUpdate yourLocation = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(coordinate, 10);
        mMap.animateCamera(yourLocation);
        mMarkerArray.add(marker);
}
```

After that I am trying to replace the Marker with another icon when ever I reached at any existing `Location`

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
{
    Log.d("latitude_main", "onlocation???");
    Geocoder geocoder;
    List<Address> addresses;
    geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
    double latitude = location.getLatitude();
    double longitude = location.getLongitude();
    Log.e("latitude_main", "latitude--" + latitude+"longitude="+longitude);

    current_lat= String.valueOf(latitude);
    current_lng= String.valueOf(longitude);
    Log.e("latitude_main","size-=="+salesmanlocationArrayList.size() );

   for(int i=0;i<salesmanlocationArrayList.size();i++)
   {           
       if(salesmanlocation.getLati().equals("12.9165757") && salesmanlocation.getLongi().equals("77.6101163"))
       {           
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                   .snippet(""+i).title(salesmanlocation.getFirm_name()+", "+salesmanlocation.getAddress())
                   .position(new LatLng(Double.valueOf(salesmanlocation.getLati().toString()), Double.valueOf(salesmanlocation.getLongi().toString())))
                   .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.event_events_select)));
       }
       mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
   }
}
```

I want to remove the marker from the map when the user visits that location.

Comment: clear previous marker from map then add new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply define one `OnMyLocationChangeListener` class that performs your tasks, and set it on your `GoogleMap` instance, this way you can use it whenever you want in your application.

**Step 1 - define your listener**

```
public class MyMarkerLocationListener implements GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener {

    List<Marker> markerList;
    int MY_DISTANCE;
    GoogleMap mMap;

    public MyMarkerLocationListener(List<Marker> markerList, int meters, GoogleMap mMap)
    {
        this.markerList = markerList;
        this.MY_DISTANCE = meters;
        this.mMap = mMap;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {

        // your code/logic
        //...

        Location myNewLocation = location;
        Location someMarkerLocation = new Location("some location");

        //for each marker on your list
        //check if you are close to it
        for (Marker m : markerList) {

            LatLng markerPosition = m.getPosition();

            someMarkerLocation.setLatitude(markerPosition.latitude);
            someMarkerLocation.setLongitude(markerPosition.longitude);

            if (myNewLocation.distanceTo(someMarkerLocation) < MY_DISTANCE) {

                //remove marker
                m.remove();

                //or if you still want to use it later
                //m.setVisible(false);

                // add your new marker
                //mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().icon()....);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

After defining your class you just set the listener on your map on your fragment or activity code =)

**Step 2 - instanciate the listener and set it**

```
MyMarkerLocationListener myListener = new MyMarkerLocationListener(mMarkerArray, 100, mMap);
mMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(myListener);
```

UPDATE to answer your question in the comments:

You should initialize mMap before using it, take a look at this piece of code from this [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31371865/replace-getmap-with-getmapasync)

```
    public class MapPane extends Activity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.map_activity);

    MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
//DO WHATEVER YOU WANT WITH GOOGLEMAP
 map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        map.setTrafficEnabled(true);
        map.setIndoorEnabled(true);
        map.setBuildingsEnabled(true);
        map.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

don't forget your activity should implement the OnMapReadyCallback interface so the onMapReady method is called

you can use the map only after it is ready

Hope this helps!

Comment: thank you for giving response but still i am getting null pointer exception

Comment: @user3881024 have you tracked where the null pointer is comming from?

Comment: @user3881024 if I were you I'd go into debug mode, line by line, step by step so I could track it down.
Also are you sure you need to call mapFragment.getMapAsync(this); inside that loop? Unless I am missing something you don't need that in this method at all

Comment: mMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(myListener);

Comment: at this line i am getting null poinnter

Comment: alright then, are you initializing mMap before mMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(myListener); ?

Comment: @user3881024 have you been able to solve your problem? I believe this answer should be marked as the correct one, let me know if this helped =)