# Changing the version of com.google.android.gms:play-services

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services, build.gradle

I have an old app that was running perfectly
Now I want to add FCM notification.

This is build.gradle (Module: app)

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'
    //compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

The first error I got was

***Error:(37, 0) Version: 7.0.0 is lower than the minimum version (9.0.0) required for google-services plugin.***

I changed the version to be 9.0.0

code has become like this

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

but I got this error

***All com.google.android.gms libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 9.0.0, 10.0.1. Examples include com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0 and com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:10.0.1 more... (Ctrl+F1)***

for that I changed the to version 10.0.1 as mentioned

the code has become like this

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
}
```

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

Now I get this error

***Error:(802, 97) error: cannot find symbol method getMap()***

the getMap function used to work fine before,

I am not sure which version of com.google.android.gms:play-services I have to use.

Thanks

Comment: use the libraries which is mentioned on documentation.

Comment: I used com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1  as mentioned in the documentation yet the error is related to com.google.android.gms:play-services

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The getMap function has been deprecated now.Check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31371865/replace-getmap-with-getmapasync) and use getMapAsync().And also keep the google services updated in the sdk manager.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.2'
```