# Google map activity doesn't show anything on api23

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-studio

I have a Google Map activity.
when i run it on Api16 emulator, everything looks fine it shows me the map.
But when i run it on Api23 emulator, it shows me a blank screen whith a google logo.
What's the problem?

Comment: Whats the code?

Comment: @JawadLeWywadi which code? as i said it shows me the map on api16 so i guess it's not a code problem

Comment: Without seeing the code it is impossible to know what you did wrong.

Answer (score 0):

We really have to see the code to know what the problem is, but it might be a depreciated api. For instance the .getmap has been replaced with getMapAsynce, but you cant just change that word to fix it. read this:
[Replace getMap with getMapAsync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31371865/replace-getmap-with-getmapasync)