# Android - Tracking using GPS, getMap deprecated

Tags: android, google-maps, gps

```
public class LocationActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        LocationListener,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private static final String TAG = "LocationActivity";
    private static final long INTERVAL = 1000 * 60 * 1; //1 minute
    private static final long FASTEST_INTERVAL = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute
    Button btnFusedLocation;
    TextView tvLocation;
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    Location mCurrentLocation;
    String mLastUpdateTime;
    GoogleMap googleMap;

    protected void createLocationRequest() {
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (!isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()) {
            finish();
        }
        createLocationRequest();
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_location_google_map);
        SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        googleMap = fm.getMap();
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to track using gps and plot the location on a map. I tried the above code but getMap is deprecated and I'm getting a screen on my phone. Could someone help me how to solve this issue?

Comment: You can follow this great answer to implement maps correctly: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31371950/2148666

Answer (score 0):

GetMap() is deprecated.You need to implement `OnMapReadyCallback` in your class

```
public class LocationActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
    LocationListener,
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, OnMapReadyCallback  {
```

And override the: `onMapReady()` function

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
    googleMap = map;
    googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
    //add code here
}
```

Also in your code add:

```
SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
fm.getMapAsync(this);
```

And in layout:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

Comment: I've tried this, but it says "Attempt to invoke getMapAsync(..) on null object reference.

Comment: did you call `fm.getMapAsync(this);` ?

Comment: yes,  MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

Comment: use: `SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
 fm.getMapAsync(this); `