# error: cannot find symbol method getMap()

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have this error: "cannot find symbol method getMap()"
please help me to solve it,i use the initilizeMap() function to load map. If map is not created it will create it for you

```
    private void initilizeMap() {
            if (googleMap == null) {
                googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                        R.id.ma`enter code here`p)).getMap();



                googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

                LatLng latLng = new LatLng(gps.getLatitude(), gps.getLongitude());
                CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 14);
                googleMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);

                //googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);
                // check if map is created successfully or not
                if (googleMap == null) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: `MapFragment` doesn't seem to have a `getMap()` method as per the javadoc (https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapFragment)

Comment: more details please

Comment: im a begginer can you help me in the code

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/31371865/2711811.  Use getMapAsync