# How to display google maps in 2D view?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, android-mapview

I have created a custom map styling following this tutorial

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sLZxAB1el6w

The issue i am facing now is that i want to display the Map in 2D view rather than the earth 3D view by default i don't want to enable compass using which i believe you can switch between 2 views.

It would be really helpful if you could share any information regarding this.

Thanks

Comment: Please check if this link helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22032874/4239410

Comment: Sorry, but i am already doing that my question is related to styling not integrating.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there is no option to restrict as only 2D view in just one option.

However you can change the settings like this.

```
GoogleMapOptions options = new GoogleMapOptions();
options.compassEnabled(false);
options.tiltGesturesEnabled(false);
options.rotateGesturesEnabled(false);

MapView mapView = new MapView(context, options);
mapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
  @Override
  public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {

  }
});
```

More options, check out the document
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMapOptions

Comment: Changing the settings doesn't really make any difference.

Answer (score 1):

I think what your looking for is the MapType:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
}
```

From the api docs :

> public static final int MAP_TYPE_HYBRID
>
> Satellite maps with a transparent layer of major streets.
>
> public static final int MAP_TYPE_NONE
>
> No base map tiles.
>
> public static final int MAP_TYPE_NORMAL
>
> Basic maps.
>
> public static final int MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE
>
> Satellite maps with no labels.
>
> public static final int MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN
>
> Terrain maps.

Hope this helps.

Comment: No that doesn't work because the styling is applied through the JSON file as explained in the video.

Answer (score 0):

For your google map instance, use animateCamera method and fix the tilt to 0 degree for CameraBuilder instance.

```
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new 
    CameraPosition.Builder().target(your_lat_long).zoom(16).tilt(0).build();

    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
}
```