# Can not perform this action after onSaveInstance

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-maps-android-api-2

I have 2 fragments, a fragment with a MapFragment and a regular details fragment.

I followed the guide by arshu here : [How to put Google Maps V2 on a Fragment Using ViewPager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19353255/how-to-put-google-maps-v2-on-a-fragment-using-viewpager)

But when I rotate my screen in the mapFragment in get an error 'Can not perform this action after onSaveInstance'.

This is probaly caused by the onDestroyView method

```
super.onDestroyView();
    if (mMap != null) {
        getActivity()
                .getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .remove(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .findFragmentById(R.id.location_map)).commit();
        mMap = null;
    }
```

But if I remove this, I get following error:

> Error inflating class fragment at CreateViewFromTag

Full code here: https://github.com/RobbySmet/ITPAppChallenge

How can I fix this or what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot commit a fragment transaction in ondestroy. Put your code in your onpause method instead.