# Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class fragment

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, fragment, android-fragmentactivity

I'm trying to build an app with a fragment, I am at a beginner level, and I have no direct solid knowledge or experience on the subject.

As it stands now, the app crashes as soon as I start it on the phone. I have paste the errorlog below. Any advice is appreciated.

Disregard, my manifest.xml had been partially deleted.

Comment: Please post the XML layout file for your fragment.

Comment: for using MapFragment please refer to this answer, it might be helpful to you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19353255/how-to-put-google-maps-v2-on-a-fragment-using-viewpager/19354359#19354359

Answer (score 0):

Pulled verbatim from your stack trace:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: A required meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not exist.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

Answer (score 0):

Add the following,

```
< meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" 
         android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" > 
< /meta-data>
```

in your manifest file immediately below the first meta-data tag(where you have placed your google api key)