# How to load a fragment over mapfragment in Android?

Tags: android, supportmapfragment, mapfragment

Map fragment will be the default fragment and on a click a new fragment should be loaded and a value has to be entered in the fragment and this value has to be passed to the map fragment

Answer (score 1):

To use MapFragment in Fragment [Follow this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19353255/how-to-put-google-maps-v2-on-a-fragment-using-viewpager)

using the Support Library to work (SupportMapFragment instead of MapFragment), so that the MapFragment can even work on below Android 3.0. You can replace the SupportMapFragment with the MapFragment if you are working on Android 3.0 or above.