# Android: google maps into a fragment

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-fragments, google-maps-android-api-2

I have spent a while trying to get this to work and I keep getting stuck somewhere at every tutorial. In short I am trying to make a tabbed app where one of the tabs it a google maps.

I have fixed all of the usual mistakes:

I have downloaded everything relevant through SDK.
I have an API key in place.
I have added compile `com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0` to my dependencies.

I am trying to follow [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25103187/5016464), but I keep getting an error.

Error I am receiving from logcat:

```
07-06 13:46:20.046  17948-17948/dolphin.dolphinapp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: dolphin.dolphinapp, PID: 17948
    java.lang.NullPointerException: IBitmapDescriptorFactory is not initialized
            at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzu.zzb(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory.zzvH(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(Unknown Source)
            at dolphin.dolphinapp.MainActivity$MapFragment.onCreateView(MainActivity.java:655)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1789)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:955)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1138)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:740)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1501)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:490)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1105)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:551)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:513)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItem(ViewPager.java:494)
            at dolphin.dolphinapp.MainActivity.onTabSelected(MainActivity.java:152)
            at android.support.v7.internal.app.WindowDecorActionBar.selectTab(WindowDecorActionBar.java:640)
            at android.support.v7.internal.app.WindowDecorActionBar$TabImpl.select(WindowDecorActionBar.java:1224)
            at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ScrollingTabContainerView$TabClickListener.onClick(ScrollingTabContainerView.java:568)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Apparently to solve this write `MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());`, but that is already in the code I copied.

Here is my Java Code:

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment {

        MapView mMapView;
        private GoogleMap googleMap;

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // inflat and return the layout
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_location_info, container,
                    false);

            mMapView = (MapView) v.findViewById(R.id.mapView);
            mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            mMapView.onResume();// needed to get the map to display immediately

            try {
                MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            MapsInitializer.initialize(getApplicationContext());

            googleMap = mMapView.getMap();
            // latitude and longitude
            double latitude = 17.385044;
            double longitude = 78.486671;


            // create marker
            MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("Hello Maps");

            // Changing marker icon
            marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ROSE));

            // adding marker
            googleMap.addMarker(marker);

            CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(new LatLng(17.385044, 78.486671)).zoom(12).build();

            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

            // Perform any camera updates here
            return v;
        }

        @Override
        public void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            mMapView.onResume();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPause() {
            super.onPause();
            mMapView.onPause();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            mMapView.onDestroy();
        }

        @Override
        public void onLowMemory() {
            super.onLowMemory();
            mMapView.onLowMemory();
        }
    }
```

My XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong

Comment: If there's nothing other than the map in your fragment, why not use [MapFragment](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapFragment) out of the box?

Comment: Sorry but I am really new to this.  How exactly would I do this?

Comment: @AlecS you should read and understand documentation before you write code https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/map

Comment: @AlecS You can simply extend from MapFragment. In that case you don't even have to override lifecycle callbacks to get some basic functionality. Like  tyczj said, try to find some good tutorial on the subject.

Answer (score 2):

you should call `mMapView.getMapAsync()` in your `onCreateView` then in the callback of `onMapReady` that you implement you would do `MapsInitializer.initialize(this.context);`

```
mMapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
           MapsInitializer.initialize(getApplicationContext());
        // latitude and longitude
        double latitude = 17.385044;
        double longitude = 78.486671;


        // create marker
        MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("Hello Maps");

        // Changing marker icon
        marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ROSE));             
    }
});
```

Comment: ok. I put that in my onCreateView. And I got `getMapAsync(com.google.androuid.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallBack) in 'com.google.android.gms.maos.MapView' cannot be applied to '()'`.
Where is `onMapReady`? is something I need to make?

Comment: you need to implement the callback like i said

Comment: I now have this `public class MapFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback{`, but I am getting the same error.

Comment: Now I am getting an error         

Class 'MapFragment" must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method 'onMapReady(GoogleMap)' in 'OnMapReadyCallback'

Comment: again you need to implement the `OnMapReady` method in your code!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82531/discussion-between-alec-s-and-tyczj).