# GoogleMap as a Fragment and not as a FragmentActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have been trying for a few days now and i just cant make it to work, Is it possible to extend a `googleMap` from `Fragment` and not `FragmentActivity`?

I use the same example code `android studio` creates as `map fragment` example and just been trying to make it into a `Fragment` and not `FragmentActivity`.

Is it possible?

I'm using target sdk21 and minsdk 21

Comment: Check out this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19353255/how-to-put-google-maps-v2-on-a-fragment-using-viewpager

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the following code in your activity/fragment where you would like to use Maps

```
<fragment
   class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
   android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
   android:id="@+id/map"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Then in your Fragment's onCreateView you can use the following code

```
private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the
        // map.
        if (mMapFragment == null) {
            // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
            mMapFragment = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));
            // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
            if (mMapFragment != null) {
                setUpMap();
            }
        }
    }
```

setup you map stuff in below mentioned method

```
private void setUpMap() {

        mMapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
             ...
            }
        }
   }
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: Thanks Rinav!, This did help me in finding the issue i had so i got it to work. :)