# Google map not displayed in Fragment subclass

Tags: android, google-maps

I am created a map and it displayed in fragment in another activity .In my application has only one Activity class.I need to display it in Fragment .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/mapAtm"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"/>


public class Atm extends Fragment {
private SupportMapFragment mSupportMapFragment;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.atm_main,
            container, false);

    mSupportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapAtm);
    if (mSupportMapFragment == null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        mSupportMapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.mapAtm, mSupportMapFragment).commit();
    }

    if (mSupportMapFragment != null) {
        mSupportMapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
                if (googleMap != null) {

                    googleMap.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(true);

                    LatLng marker_latlng = new LatLng(150, -150);

                    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(marker_latlng).zoom(15.0f).build();
                    CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition);
                    googleMap.moveCamera(cameraUpdate);

                }

            }
        });


    }
    return view;
}
}
```

Their is no error in Emulator.But after installing in Mobile;application will terminate when clicking in Atm Map

Comment: It must be terminating due to error. Find that error

Comment: What is the error you are getting after the application terminates? Check it.

Comment: Provide how to implement map in fragment

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start

Comment: The above link shows all the steps to implement google maps. If you have implemented the above steps then check what error you are getting on termination.

Comment: I need to display map in Fragment

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/19354359/2170074

Comment: please show your LOGCAT