# Adding A GoogleMap to a Fragment Programmatically

Tags: android, google-maps, fragment, deprecated

I've been trying my best to work around this issue for a few days and I've read suggestions from other StackOverFlow posts in addition to plenty of Google searches. I think the main issue is that the 'getMap()' method has been deprecated to make way for 'getMapAsync()' and the explanations for using the latter don't fit with how I want to use it. So, with this in mind, I figured a question might be relevant to others as well at this point.

Basically, so far I've created a menu out of buttons that allow the user to switch between Fragments. One of these Fragments needs to be a GoogleMap which will start on a button press, keeping the buttons in view.

I got my MapsActivity code from: -http://www.joellipman.com/articles/google/android/application-development/android-os-add-googlemap-as-fragment.html - but as mentioned, getMap() is deprecated. I also looked at -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19353255/how-to-put-google-maps-v2-on-a-fragment-using-viewpager - but the problem is the same.

MainActivity...

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button mapMenuItem, postcodeMenuItem, nameMenuItem, recentMenuItem;
    ConnectivityManager conMgr;
    NetworkInfo networkInfo;
    FrameLayout fragmentContainer;
    NameFragment nf;
    String longiString, latiString;

    public static FragmentManager fragmentManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mapMenuItem = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mapButton);
        postcodeMenuItem = (Button) findViewById(R.id.postcodeButton);
        nameMenuItem = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nameButton);
        recentMenuItem = (Button) findViewById(R.id.recentButton);
        fragmentContainer = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.fragmentContainer);

        fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

 }
      public void searchMap(View v) {
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        MapFragment mf = new MapFragment();
        ft.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, mf);
        ft.commit();

        mapMenuItem.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#fece35"));
        nameMenuItem.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#eff169"));
        postcodeMenuItem.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#eff169"));
        recentMenuItem.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#eff169"));

    }
}
```

MapFragment...

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment {

    MapView mapView;
    GoogleMap gMap;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_fragment, container, false);
        mapView = (MapView) v.findViewById((R.id.mapView));
        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mapView.onResume();

        try{
            MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        gMap = mapView.getMap();
        double latitude = 17.385044;
        double longitude = 78.486671;

        //create marker
        MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(
                new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("Hello Maps");

        //changing marker icon
        marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ROSE));

        //adding marker
        gMap.addMarker(marker);
        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(
                new LatLng(17.385044, 78.486671)).zoom(12).build();
        gMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));


        //Perform any camera updates
        return v;

    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mapView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mapView.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mapView.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        mapView.onLowMemory();
    }
}
```

MapLayout...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:apiKey="@string/google_maps_key"
        android:clickable="false"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

ActivityLayout...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#72a972"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    tools:context="uk.ac.mmu.webmd.foodhygieneapp.MainActivity">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rel_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:background="#eff169"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/mapButton"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#eff169"
            android:onClick="searchMap"
            android:text="@string/MapsButton" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/nameButton"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/mapButton"
            android:background="#eff169"
            android:onClick="nameMenu"
            android:text="@string/NameButton" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/postcodeButton"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/recentButton"
            android:background="#eff169"
            android:onClick="postcodeMenu"
            android:text="@string/PostcodeButton" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/recentButton"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="#eff169"
            android:onClick="recentMenu"
            android:text="@string/RecentButton" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </FrameLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: and what is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[How to put Google Maps V2 on a Fragment Using ViewPager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19353255/how-to-put-google-maps-v2-on-a-fragment-using-viewpager?lq=1)

Turns out the answer was here all along, sorry for wasting peoples time!

Answer (score 2):

Here's the code I use to create a map without using any layout XML. It's derived from a number of posts, each contributing an essential component of the picture, so thanks to all those authors. It's designed to run in a support class so the Activity has to be passed in. The result is a self-contained FrameLayout with a map inside it, so it can be added to any layout you may already have in your app, allowing you to have the map occupy just a portion of the screen.

```
package pro.scanna.easycoder.android.handler;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

import pro.scanna.R;

public class ProgrammaticMap {

    public void create(final AppCompatActivity activity, final ViewGroup parent) {

        FrameLayout frame = new FrameLayout(activity);
        frame.setId(R.id.reservedNamedId);
        frame.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
           FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
           FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        parent.addView(frame);

        FragmentTransaction transaction =
           activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        SupportMapFragment fragment = new SupportMapFragment();
        transaction.add(frame.getId(), fragment);
        transaction.commit();

        try {
            MapsInitializer.initialize(activity);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        fragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
                setupMap(map);
            }
        });
    }

    private void setupMap(final GoogleMap map) {

        double latitude = 0;   // set this
        double longitude = 0;  // set this too
        float zoom = 17f;      // or whatever, between 2 and 21 (approx)

        map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
            new LatLng(latitude, longitude), zoom), 1000,
               new GoogleMap.CancelableCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                doneSetup();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                doneSetup();
            }
        });

        map.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onMapClick(LatLng location)
            {
                // Here when the map is tapped
            }
        });
    }

    private void doneSetup() {
        // Do whatever comes next
    }
}
```

A single resource is needed for the id of the frame. Do this by creating a resource file called `res/values/ids.xml`, with the following contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <item name="reservedNamedId" type="id"/>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a FrameLayout as a container to hold the map fragment in any layout -

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Then programmatically add it -

```
MapFragment mapFragment = MapFragment.newInstance();
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        getFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.map, mapFragment)
                .commit();
```

Use `getChildFragmentManager()` if adding the map fragment inside a Fragment itself.

Use `getSupportFragmentManager()` if you're using a `SupportMapFragment` instance.

Answer (score 0):

To load map programmatically,

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();    SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment =    SupportMapFragment.newInstance();    fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mapContainer, supportMapFragment).commit();
```

In xml:

```
<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/mapContainer" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```