# getMapAsync in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am using Sliding Tabs with different fragments. In map fragment I cannot use Nested Fragment as XML. Below is Java code and XMLfile.
I am stuck at `getMapAsync()` method So How Can I get Map using `getMapAsync` without Any exception? I will really appreciate your cooperation.

Food Fragment Java:

```
public class FoodFragment extends Fragment {

private SupportMapFragment mapfragment;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.food_layout, null);

mapfragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.maps_frame);
if (mapfragment == null) {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    mapfragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.maps_frame,mapfragment).commit();
}
mapfragment.getMapAsync((OnMapReadyCallback) getActivity().getApplicationContext());

return view;

 }
}
```

Food XML file,

```
  <FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="2in"
    android:id="@+id/maps_frame"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

  </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: What exception are you getting now ?

Comment: thanks for your coment and the exception is :  " android.app.Application cannot be cast to com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `ApplicationContext` cannot be casts as `OnMapReadyCallback` you can create new instance of `OnMapReadyCallback()` as an anonymous class instead like here is what you might be searching for

```
  mapfragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
        @Override public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
            if (googleMap != null) {
               // your additional codes goes here
               .....
            }
   }
```

You can refer [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32091722/5067493) as well if you need.