# "Unable to get provider com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" Error path Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have an Application which is connected to firebase.The problem is when install the app in device(working on several devices).I read a lot of forums and no one works.I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37328890/android-firebase-dynamitemodule-failed-to-load-module-descriptor) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37790190/google-map-implementation-in-viewpager-error-unable-to-get-provider-com-google) and so on.Thanks!!

The error is here.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.dev.ptruck, PID: 8833
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.dev.ptruck-17.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.dev.ptruck-17, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5196)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4788)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4728)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:166)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1343)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5584)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
               Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.dev.ptruck-17.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.dev.ptruck-17, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
                  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
                  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5181)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4788) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4728) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:166) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1343) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5584) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084) 
                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is the start Class

```
public class StartActivity extends Activity {
private static final String FIREBASE_URL = "https://database.firebaseio.com/";
private Firebase myFirebaseRef = null;
View rootView;
String uid;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);

    Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
    final ProgressBar p = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.start_progress_bar);

}
private void checkUserLogin() {
                    myFirebaseRef.addAuthStateListener(new Firebase.AuthStateListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAuthStateChanged(AuthData authData) {
                            if (authData != null) {

                                System.out.println(myFirebaseRef.getKey());
                                Intent toMainActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MenuActivity.class);
                                uid = myFirebaseRef.getAuth().getUid();
                                toMainActivity.putExtra("user_id", uid);
                                finish();
                                startActivity(toMainActivity);

                            } else if (authData == null) {

                                Intent toMainActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
                                startActivity(toMainActivity);
                                // user is not logged in
                            }
                        }
                    });
}
private Runnable task = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {

        checkUserLogin();
    }
};
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if(myFirebaseRef == null) {
        myFirebaseRef = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL);
    }
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(task, 3000);

}
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    unbindDrawables(rootView);
    rootView = null;
    System.gc();

}
protected void unbindDrawables(View view) {
    if (view != null) {
        if (view.getBackground() != null) {
            view.getBackground().setCallback(null);
        }
        if (view instanceof ViewGroup && !(view instanceof AdapterView)) {
            for (int i = 0; i < ((ViewGroup) view).getChildCount(); i++) {
                unbindDrawables(((ViewGroup) view).getChildAt(i));
            }
            ((ViewGroup) view).removeAllViews();
        }

    }

}
```

}

Comment: try this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37360126/getting-exception-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-google-firebase-firebaseop

Comment: Where is your code

Comment: Thanks, but not working!

Comment: Post the dependencies section of your build.gradle file.

Comment: This worked for me http://stackoverflow.com/a/38224316/4663544

Comment: I faced exactly the same problem,and got it solved using http://stackoverflow.com/a/40040720/3994271

Comment: See my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39825543/didnt-find-class-com-google-firebase-provider-firebaseinitprovider/55913295#55913295

Answer (score 84, accepted):

I have also faced same problem with Firebase when run application below API 19(< 4.4.2) devices due to error of `Multidex`. Then below **solution** work for me:

In app module build.gradle

```
android {
   ...
   defaultConfig {
       multiDexEnabled true
       ...
   }
}

dependencies {
  // add dependency 
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}

// ADD THIS AT THE BOTTOM
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

update name in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:name=".MyApplication"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

     // ...
</application>
```

Crate a MyApplication.java file

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
       super.attachBaseContext(base);
       MultiDex.install(this);
    }

}
```

Comment: I was missing the last step to override attachBaseContext. Works after adding.

Comment: Adding attachBaseContext method solved my crash issue of Kitkat . It was working fine in all the above versions without this method.

Comment: `Plugin with id 'com.google.gms.google-services' not found.`

Answer (score 25):

In AndroidStudio try to do this:

> 1. ctrl+alt+s
> 2. Click on "Build, Execution, Deployment
> 3. disable "Instant Run"

This should work

Comment: Omg, what a Android Studio fail.

Comment: This worked for me, not the multidex solution. So I cannot use instant run anymore ?

Comment: Instant run is a painful feature in android studio!

Comment: After 4 hours of debugging. This worked for me. I would have never thought this will work. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Disabling instant run fixed the issue for me.

Android Studio -> Preferences -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Instant Run

-Uncheck the box next to "Enable Instant Run..."

-Click OK

Comment: You may read above answers before you post a duplicate one. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue, what i did is uninstall the app from device/emulator, and then, reinstall it again (from Android Studio, 'run' button).

Answer (score 0):

If you have recently changed the firebase dependency version in your gradle you may need to update to the latest version of Google Repository in the Android SDK manager as well.

If you cannot update the Google Repository at the time, try changing the gradle dependency version back to lower.

Answer (score -1):

Just insert below lines in your project `AndroidManifest.xml` file,
if they're not in **application** tag

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```