# Firebase Performance crashing in API 19 with Google Play Services 10.2.98

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-performance

This week I started testing the new Firebase Performance in my new app. Once I am using Firebase for other features like Auth and DB I already updated all packages to last 10.2.6 Firebase version and follow all pre req instructions.

minAPI is 19.

My problem is App is crashing only in API 19 with Google Play Services 10.2.98 in a real Galaxy Duos device running Android 4.4.1. When App starts it could not find firebase-perf in device.

It is only happening with this package and in other devices and higher versions everything is fine and I can see data in Firebase Performance Dashboard.

Tips ?

Stacktrace below

Regards,

```
Process: com.mobilecodelabs.fb.trampo, PID: 2727
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.firebase.perf.provider.FirebasePerfProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.perf.provider.FirebasePerfProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.mobilecodelabs.fb.trampo-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.mobilecodelabs.fb.trampo-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4793)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4385)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4325)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.perf.provider.FirebasePerfProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.mobilecodelabs.fb.trampo-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.mobilecodelabs.fb.trampo-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4778)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4385) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4325) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Prompt the user to update Google Play Services before proceed? Blacklist the device from the Google Play Console to prevent the downloads?

Comment: It still in dev. I can do both your suggestions, but what is strange Firebase documentation require minimal version 10.2.6 and device version is higher 10.2.98.

Comment: Oh, if you are in dev you can't say for sure that the problem is the device or your implementation (which maybe need a custom tweak in some cases). Or you have used some online services to perform tests on hundreds of devices?

Comment: I have tested in a lot of REAL devices, Samsung (S5, S6, S7,J5,J7, Galaxy Duos), LG (K10), Motorola (G4, G5), Blue, Sony Z, with Android 4.4, 6.x, 5.x, 5.1x, 7.x. I tested in dozen of emulator configs from API 19 to 24 using Google SDK. I tested in TestLab Real devices and emulators from API 19 to 23. All emulators with API 19, local and google, I got same error.

Comment: To verify that is not a problem in my code or emulator config I got a real device with API 19 with is one Samsung Galaxy Duos with API 19 as well I tested in Google TestLab for real devices with API 19. The App ONLY crash in devices with API 19, doesn't matter if it is emulator or real.

Comment: I have other 10 Firebase packages, Auth, DB, Storage, Config, Ads, etc, etc, and only Performance is failing

Comment: If you're seeing a crash, you should post a stack trace so we can see what's going on.

Comment: Very [similar looking stack traces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39825543/didnt-find-class-com-google-firebase-provider-firebaseinitprovider) (although for different missing class) have been corrected by enabling [Multidex](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html).  From your previous comment ("10 Firebase packages"), it sounds like your app could be very large. Try using the [APK Analyzer](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/apk-analyzer.html) to see if you need Multidex.

Comment: Thanks @BobSnyder. I SOLVED the problem but I confess I did not understand the solution :-). I was using "@AddTrace" directive to instrument my code. In APK Analyzer I saw AddTrace was used but other named AppTraceStart is not. I changed my code and removed "@AddTrace" directive and started use Trace class with .start(), etc. For some reason it is working in API 19 and other versions too. I will make more tests later.

Comment: @koridallos Would you mind reaching out to Firebase support with a minimal project that reproduces the problem, and link back to this post? https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/

Answer (score 1):

This is an old issue but posting an update for the benefit of others.

I have run into this issue my self with the exact same stack trace. My app is failing on API 19 and below, where as on 21+ it works without any issue. For me it turned out to be a MultiDex issue.

Even though I had enabled MultiDex by giving

- multiDexEnabled true in Module gradle file under "defaultConfig" for API 21+
- "implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'" in Module gradle file under "dependencies" for API 20 and below my app failed with the above exception.

I had to make changes to the manifest file and replaced the fully qualified class name of my app with "android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myapp">
    <application
            android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" >
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Please read this page on [Multidex](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex) for further details.
And here is the reference for the [application](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element#space) attribute. 
I have tested my app in the Firebase test labs and physical devices and it works on all versions from API 17 to API 28.

Answer (score 1):

Check this first

```
defaultConfig {
 multiDexEnabled true
}
dependencies {
 implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
}
```

Then in Application class adding this solved this problem

```
 @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }
```