# Firebase performance monitoring issues

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-performance

I enabled Firebase performance monitoring as per the doc - https://firebase.google.com/docs/perf-mon/get-started-android

I have included compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:10.2.6' in my app/build.gradle. I am using google play library 11.0.0

However when I start my application I get following exception.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method zzb(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; in class Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/zzac; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzac' appears in /data/app/com.lonelyplanet.guides-1/base.apk:classes70.dex)
at com.google.firebase.perf.provider.FirebasePerfProvider.zza(Unknown Source)
at com.google.firebase.perf.provider.FirebasePerfProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source)
at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5811)
at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5403)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5342)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1528)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

Comment: You should use the same version of all Firebase and Google Play libraries. Don't mix 10.2.6 and 11.0.0.  A similar stack trace appears at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44170073/4815718.

Comment: Yup that was the issue!