# App Crashed in ANDROID SDK 17, but in other versions not

Tags: android, firebase

Error message:

Update:
Now only shows this message

```
06-11 20:05:37.912 1861-1861/com.google.process.gapps E/NetworkScheduler.SR: Invalid parameter app
06-11 20:05:37.912 1861-1861/com.google.process.gapps E/NetworkScheduler.SR: Invalid package name : Perhaps you didn't include a PendingIntent in the extras?
06-11 20:05:37.932 2197-2285/com.google.android.gms E/Drive.UninstallOperation: Package still installed mx.com.epcon.toffers
06-11 20:05:37.952 2197-3866/com.google.android.gms E/IntentOperationSvc: Failed to instantiate Chimera operation impl, dropping operation
06-11 20:05:38.022 1861-1861/com.google.process.gapps E/NetworkScheduler.SR: Invalid parameter app
06-11 20:05:38.022 1861-1861/com.google.process.gapps E/NetworkScheduler.SR: Invalid package name : Perhaps you didn't include a PendingIntent in the extras?
06-11 20:05:38.632 3893-3899/? E/jdwp: Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
06-11 20:05:38.642 3893-3893/? E/Trace: error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
06-11 20:05:38.642 3893-3893/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" on path: /data/app/mx.com.epcon.toffers-2.apk
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4822)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4432)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4372)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:141)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1294)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
                                                     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" on path: /data/app/mx.com.epcon.toffers-2.apk
                                                     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
                                                     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
                                                     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4807)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4432) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4372) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:141) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1294) 
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041) 
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) 
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560) 
                                                     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
06-11 20:05:38.692 1158-1594/? E/SurfaceFlinger: ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
06-11 20:05:38.712 1158-1594/? E/SurfaceFlinger: ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
```

Solved:
I solved it adding android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" in Manifest and in Gradle (app) added this compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

Comment: Please ensure that all Firebase dependency versions are the exact same

Comment: I'll check thanks, and what is the correct format for errors here?

Comment: I only have this: compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.1' and all the google play services are the same 10.2.1 @cricket_007

Comment: Hmm. Okay. Are you using Proguard, by chance? (Unless you are making a release APK, that's a no). Generally, the `{}` button is used for code and logs (indent four spaces), and the quote button is quoting things

Comment: You may need to enable Multidex.  See this post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39825543/4815718

Comment: I solved it, I only added this android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"

Comment: Thanks @BobSnyder I was searching and found it ;)... Thanks mates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: I solved it adding android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" in Manifest and in Gradle (app) added this compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'