# Firebase ads dependency causes app to crash

Tags: firebase, admob

I have an application that runs fine with other Firebase components but immediately I add

> compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.2.4'

it crashes with the error messages below. Note that removing the ads dependency and rebuilding it makes it to run again, kindly help I've been stuck for hours.

```
10-24 09:01:46.662 28767-28767/daftari.diary.com E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                               Process: daftari.diary.com, PID: 28767
                                                               java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{daftari.diary.com/daftari.diary.com.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "daftari.diary.com.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/daftari.diary.com-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/daftari.diary.com-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2297)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2441)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:151)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354)
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5345)
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:828)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:644)
                                                                   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "daftari.diary.com.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/daftari.diary.com-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/daftari.diary.com-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
                                                                   at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                                                   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
                                                                   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
                                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2288)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2441) 
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354) 
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5345) 
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:828) 
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:644) 
                                                                   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: try solutions provided in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39825543/didnt-find-class-com-google-firebase-provider-firebaseinitprovider

Comment: Thanks Amod...Adding multidex support solved the problem

Comment: Unrelated to the problem, but just to let you know: the latest version of firebase-ads is 11.4.2. It's always good to use the most recent one.