# Android Application using Firebase database keeps crashing when launching?

Tags: java, android, firebase

So I am currently trying to store user details into a database, however the program does not mention any errors upon execution, but the application keeps on crashing when trying to open it. This is my error code in logcat:[image: Error]

Code gist will be provided upon request

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.finalyearprojectapp"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:22.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'

}
```

Comment: Can you add your imports too?

Comment: added my build.gradle which i assume is imports?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding multidex support

```
defaultConfig {
    // Your previous stuffs
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

for more info you can visit this thread. This can be helpful too: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39831657/7237222