# Adding MultiDex to a project in android studio but keeping getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, android

So I am currently trying to import multidex into my project, I have followed the provided documentations/QnA
[Android Application using Firebase database keeps crashing when launching?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66838071/android-application-using-firebase-database-keeps-crashing-when-launching/66838216#66838216)

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex#java

and have done the following amends to my build.gradle app file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.finalyearprojectapp"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            multiDexKeepFile file('multidex-config.txt')
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}


dependencies {
    implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1"
    //implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:22.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'

}
```

I have followed the documentation until it has mentioned that I am needed to implement the following code into my android manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myapp">
    <application
            android:name="androidx.multidex.MultiDexApplication" >
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I have added this to the manifest, my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.finalyearprojectapp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"  />


    <application

        android:name="androidx.multidex.MultiDexApplication" >

        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainScreen" />
        <activity android:name=".RegisterActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".LoginActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

But now I run across this error

```
Failed to parse XML in C:\Users\jabze\Desktop\FinalApp\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml
ParseError at [row,col]:[11,43]
Message: expected start or end tag
Affected Modules: app
```

I have done literally every tutorial out there and I just cannot figure out the issue, i feel like giving up on this project.

I have tried extending it from each class as mentioned in documentation and all my code has errors to resolve, some with no context.

I have tried extending it using a base class which uses multidex and then trying to add it into the android manifest like this,

```
android:name=".BaseApp"
```

Then creating a class to extend from multidex

```
import androidx.multidex.MultiDexApplication;

public class BaseApp extends MultiDexApplication {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

}
```

This has solved the configuration problem, but now i recieve a error when trying to open my app, logcat

```
2021-03-29 00:28:45.035 31916-31916/? I/lyearprojectap: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
2021-03-29 00:28:45.054 31916-31916/? I/lyearprojectap: Unquickening 12 vdex files!
2021-03-29 00:28:45.055 31916-31916/? W/lyearprojectap: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
2021-03-29 00:28:45.150 31916-31916/com.example.finalyearprojectapp D/ApplicationLoaders: Returning zygote-cached class loader: /system/framework/android.test.base.jar
2021-03-29 00:28:45.395 31916-31916/com.example.finalyearprojectapp D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
2021-03-29 00:28:45.395 31916-31916/com.example.finalyearprojectapp D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
2021-03-29 00:28:45.398 31916-31916/com.example.finalyearprojectapp I/MultiDex: VM with version 2.1.0 has multidex support
2021-03-29 00:28:45.398 31916-31916/com.example.finalyearprojectapp I/MultiDex: Installing application
2021-03-29 00:28:45.399 31916-31916/com.example.finalyearprojectapp I/MultiDex: VM has multidex support, MultiDex support library is disabled.
2021-03-29 00:28:45.419 31916-31916/com.example.finalyearprojectapp W/ComponentDiscovery: Class com.google.firebase.dynamicloading.DynamicLoadingRegistrar is not an found.
2021-03-29 00:28:45.435 31916-31916/com.example.finalyearprojectapp I/FirebaseApp: Device unlocked: initializing all Firebase APIs for app [DEFAULT]
2021-03-29 00:28:45.529 31916-31977/com.example.finalyearprojectapp W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
2021-03-29 00:28:45.564 31916-31916/com.example.finalyearprojectapp D/FirebaseAuth: Notifying id token listeners about user ( v9NWiRcvjMTz4y8V8kXy6f7RZdQ2 ).
2021-03-29 00:28:45.566 31916-31916/com.example.finalyearprojectapp D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2021-03-29 00:28:45.567 31916-31916/com.example.finalyearprojectapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.finalyearprojectapp, PID: 31916
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/firebase/FirebaseApp$IdTokenListenersCountChangedListener;
        at com.google.firebase.auth.zzp.create(Unknown Source:3)
        at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime.lambda$discoverComponents$0(ComponentRuntime.java:132)
        at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime$$Lambda$1.get(Unknown Source:4)
        at com.google.firebase.components.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:53)
        at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime.doInitializeEagerComponents(ComponentRuntime.java:291)
        at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime.initializeEagerComponents(ComponentRuntime.java:281)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeAllApis(FirebaseApp.java:584)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(FirebaseApp.java:303)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(FirebaseApp.java:267)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(FirebaseApp.java:252)
        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(FirebaseInitProvider.java:51)
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:2388)
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:2358)
        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(FirebaseInitProvider.java:45)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:7239)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6780)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6697)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:237)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1913)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp$IdTokenListenersCountChangedListener" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~yUZ3UTW9uE5Wv9gw7MBIVA==/com.example.finalyearprojectapp-ZqPMbXUiTbtxIQSglqq2dg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~yUZ3UTW9uE5Wv9gw7MBIVA==/com.example.finalyearprojectapp-ZqPMbXUiTbtxIQSglqq2dg==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system_ext/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:207)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at com.google.firebase.auth.zzp.create(Unknown Source:3) 
        at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime.lambda$discoverComponents$0(ComponentRuntime.java:132) 
        at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime$$Lambda$1.get(Unknown Source:4) 
        at com.google.firebase.components.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:53) 
        at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime.doInitializeEagerComponents(ComponentRuntime.java:291) 
        at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime.initializeEagerComponents(ComponentRuntime.java:281) 
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeAllApis(FirebaseApp.java:584) 
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(FirebaseApp.java:303) 
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(FirebaseApp.java:267) 
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(FirebaseApp.java:252) 
        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(FirebaseInitProvider.java:51) 
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:2388) 
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:2358) 
        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(FirebaseInitProvider.java:45) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:7239) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6780) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6697) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:237) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1913) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947) 
2021-03-29 00:28:45.654 31916-31979/com.example.finalyearprojectapp W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
2021-03-29 00:28:45.667 31916-31979/com.example.finalyearprojectapp I/FirebaseAuth: [FirebaseAuth:] Loading module via FirebaseOptions.
2021-03-29 00:28:45.667 31916-31979/com.example.finalyearprojectapp I/FirebaseAuth: [FirebaseAuth:] Preparing to create service connection to gms implementation
```

Comment: how come you have something like this -> android:name="androidx.multidex.MultiDexApplication" >  should it not be something like this ->  android:name=".BaseApplication" and then you can extent MultiDexApplication from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to create a Base class that extends the MultiDex if you don't have one.

```
public class BaseApp extends MultiDexApplication {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

}
```

Your Manifest can look like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.finalyearprojectapp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"  />

   <application
    android:name=".BaseApp"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name=".MainScreen" />
        <activity android:name=".RegisterActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".LoginActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

> Edit:
> You should upgrade your firebase to the latest, or at least version from 17.0.0 and above.
> I was told that According to firebase release notes May 07, 2019, it says; "If you use Firebase Authentication, update to firebase-auth v17.0.0 or later to ensure functionality alignment with other updated Firebase libraries."

Comment: I have tried this method, it has solved the issue for syncing, but now I have the issue of unable to run my app, i have provided the logcat of the issue.

Comment: @Jaber2599 this is a firebase issue, update your firebase to the latest and you should be good.

Comment: THIS HAS WORKED! Thanks a ton!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!