# Firebase android: Multidex error after updating dependencies

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

**These are my current dependencies and they work fine:**

These dependencies in my build.gradle (app):

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.4.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.4.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ui-database:3.1.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.4.2'
```

And this dependency in my build.gradle (project_name):

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
```

**But when I update to new versions of firebase I get multidex error:**

These dependencies in my build.gradle (app):

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1' 
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ui-database:4.1.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1'
```

And this dependency in my build.gradle (project_name):

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
```

**Problem**

So my problem is getting multi dex error when trying to build my project with the updated dependecies.

I have `android studio (3.1.3)`.

Why is it happening?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you added multidex support library and set it to enable ?

Comment: Do you have `multiDexEnabled true`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enable multidexing with the new Android Multidex support library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26609734/how-to-enable-multidexing-with-the-new-android-multidex-support-library)

Comment: @crammeur no I dont have it enabled.

Comment: @Raj what is the multidex support library

Comment: What exactly does the error say?

Comment: Read this doc https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex

Comment: try this  hope this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39206299/unable-to-get-provider-com-google-firebase-provider-firebaseinitprovider-error/41444469#41444469

Comment: @Raj I read multi dex support is only for lollipop and above?

Comment: Just try to implement that in your app and see if it works @data

Comment: @Raj the error is still there?

Comment: @Raj It says (Multiple dex files define Landroid/arch/core/util/Function).

Comment: Send the complete error details @data

Answer (score 0):

make sure modify your build.gradle and Enabling multidex.

```
     defaultConfig {
         minSdkVersion 14 //lower than 14 doesn't support multidex
         targetSdkVersion 22

         //Enabling this multidex support.
         multiDexEnabled true
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

try enabling multidex.

Open project/app/build.gradle and add

```
defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

and

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
```

and enable Jetifier.
Open project/android/app/gradle.properties and add following lines.

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```