# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" on path: DexPathList

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, android-multidex

This is as typical error from MultiDex, but in flutter I can't solve.
The error in logcat is:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" on path: DexPathList
```

But in flutter we have to use `FlutterActivity` in `MainApplication` so I can't do much of solution recommended.
And When I use `MultiDex.install(this);` I receive this error:

```
error: cannot find symbol
    MultiDex.install(this);
```

How can I Solve this problem? I need to use Firebase in sdk 19 (Android 4.4) .

Comment: GO through this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39825543/didnt-find-class-com-google-firebase-provider-firebaseinitprovider

Comment: did not work to me.

Comment: please can you check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39206299/unable-to-get-provider-com-google-firebase-provider-firebaseinitprovider-error/41444469