# Add google map in fragment activity in android studio

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, android-fragments

I am trying to add google map in fragment activity but it is creating an error at `getMap();`method in AddMasjid.java

AddMasjid.java

```
package com.example.saroosh.masjidnow.Tabs;

import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.example.saroosh.masjidnow.R;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class AddMasjid extends Fragment {

    MapView mMapView;
    private GoogleMap googleMap;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v =inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_masjid,container,false);

        mMapView = (MapView) v.findViewById(R.id.map);
        mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mMapView.onResume();// needed to get the map to display immediately

        try {
            MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        googleMap = mMapView.getMap();
        // latitude and longitude
        double latitude = 17.385044;
        double longitude = 78.486671;

        // create marker
        MarkerOptions marker;
        marker = new MarkerOptions().position(
                new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("Hello Maps");

        // Changing marker icon
        marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ROSE));

        // adding marker
        googleMap.addMarker(marker);
        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                .target(new LatLng(17.385044, 78.486671)).zoom(12).build();
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));



        return v;
    }

}
```

add_masjid.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:text="@string/xyz"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/generalId"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/rect1"
        android:onClick="geoLocate"
        android:text="@string/abc"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/generalId"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/generalId"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/generalId"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:labelFor="@+id/editText1" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/generalId" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

After putting and API key and some permissions in manifest file. Please guide me how can I get google map in fragment activity.

Comment: Possible duplicated: [How to put Google Maps V2 on a Fragment Using ViewPager](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19353255/how-to-put-google-maps-v2-on-a-fragment-using-viewpager)

Comment: You need to do using *support map fragment* as you have taken in *xml* not *map view*.

Comment: add Logcat errors for more details please.

Comment: @W4R10CK I can't get logcat error because i am getting error in writing. Could you tell me? How I can get google map in tab or viewPager?

Comment: please add the screenshot of error that u getting.

Comment: You might want to check on how to add [*MapFragment*](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/map#add_a_fragment). You might have miss a step or codes. This tutorial about [Android - Google Maps Tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_google_maps.htm) might help as it also discuss how to properly add `GoogleMap` and `MapFragment` api to integrate map in your android application.