# Launch Maps with current location

Tags: google-maps, android-fragments, android-viewpager, google-maps-android-api-2

My app is using a `ViewPager` with three `fragments`. The main fragment, when the app launches, will show a Map fragment with devices' current location as a marker and the other two fragments will use the devices' location, to show content. I am running into couple of challenges:

1. I cannot launch the Map fragment with the marker of devices' current location. I ensured the permissions are granted - also, as I understand displaying the map is independent of permissions; for getting devices' location, you will need permissions and runtime permissions if you are on 6.0 and above. Is my understanding correct?
2. I am unable to determine the correct mechanism to send the devices' current location to the other two fragments as I swipe over from the Map fragment. I tried using interfaces, bundle, eventbus but neither worked.

Comment: Check this [SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19353255/how-to-put-google-maps-v2-on-a-fragment-using-viewpager) with regard to ViewPager and fragments.

Comment: Thank you for the link but I am looking to launch my app with the current location (not a static location) as a marker much like Google Maps.