# Android GoogleMap ,Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.bo.v()'

Tags: android, android-maps-v2

Im attempting to display my GPS position on Google maps &  also position of others as data is made available.

**Here is my fragment that loads the map fragment:**

```
    package xyz.fragments;


    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.FragmentManager;
    import android.location.Location;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Handler;
    import android.os.Looper;
    import android.os.Message;
    import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
    import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;

    import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

    import xyzR;

    public class IncidentMapFragment extends SupportMapFragment  implements OnMapReadyCallback {


        public static IncidentMapFragment newInstance()
        {
            return new IncidentMapFragment();
        }
        private  SupportMapFragment mapFragment;
        private static GoogleMap map;
        public static final int UPDATE_MY_CURRENT_LOCATION = 0;
        public static final int UPDATE_MY_TEAMS_CURRENT_LOCATIONS = 1;
        public static final int UPDATE_ALL_TEAMS_CURRENT_LOCATIONS = 2;

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.incident_map_fragment, container, false);
   //I ALSO tried getFragmentManager()
            mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)getChildFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.incident_map);
 //THE NULLPOINTER when accessing  mapFragment IS AT THIS  LINE
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

            return rootView;
        }


        public static final Handler updateIncidentMap = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) {
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                final int what = msg.what;
                switch(what) {
                    case UPDATE_MY_CURRENT_LOCATION:
                         Location myCurrentLocation = (Location) msg.obj;
                        if (map!=null && myCurrentLocation!=null) {
                            myKeyOntheMap(map,myCurrentLocation);
                        }
                        break;
                    case UPDATE_MY_TEAMS_CURRENT_LOCATIONS:
                        break;
                    case UPDATE_ALL_TEAMS_CURRENT_LOCATIONS:
                        break;
                    default: break;
                }
            }
        };

        @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
            map = googleMap;

        }

        private static void myKeyOntheMap( GoogleMap map,Location location)
        {
            LatLng myPos = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(myPos)
                    .title("You"));
            map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(myPos));
        }
    }
```

incident_map_fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true">
    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/incident_map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
         />
</ScrollView>
```

**Im getting:** Android GoogleMap java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.bo.v()' at code line  `mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);`

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In fragment the `SupportMapFragment` not working... to solved this problem Use `MapView`..
for use `MapView` in `fragment` see this answer...
https://stackoverflow.com/a/19354359/9868485

Comment: After searching SO more, I saw a suggestion to  change  `IncidentMapFragment extends SupportMapFragment` to  'IncidentMapFragment extends Fragment' and now it works.