# Google Maps does not display in fragment

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-studio, maps

I apologise if I'm posting a question that is similar to many others but each of them have different implementations of the google map and to try them all means to completely break my code and since I'm new to Android Development I'd rather not risk it if you can help me find out what is wrong with my map. Thanks.

When I run my app this is what I get:
[image]

This is my Gradle.build (app):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.binfo"
        minSdkVersion 27
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
//    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.1.1'
}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

My Manifest:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.binfo" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/BINFO_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY"/>

        <activity android:name="com.example.binfo.MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">    <!--custom theme properties to be used for this activity-->

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
    </application>

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>


</manifest>
```

My fragment xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".HomeFragment">

    <fragment
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:id="@+id/frg"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

and my fragment java:

```java
package com.example.binfo;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptor;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;


public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    public void mapFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frg);  //use SuppoprtMapFragment for using in fragment instead of activity  MapFragment = activity   SupportMapFragment = fragment
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapReady(GoogleMap mMap) {
                mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

                mMap.clear(); //clear old markers

                CameraPosition googlePlex = CameraPosition.builder()
                        .target(new LatLng(37.4219999,-122.0862462))
                        .zoom(10)
                        .bearing(0)
                        .tilt(45)
                        .build();

                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(googlePlex), 10000, null);

                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(new LatLng(37.4219999, -122.0862462))
                        .title("Spider Man")
                        .icon(bitmapDescriptorFromVector(getActivity(),R.drawable.spider)));

                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(new LatLng(37.4629101,-122.2449094))
                        .title("Iron Man")
                        .snippet("His Talent : Plenty of money"));

                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(new LatLng(37.3092293,-122.1136845))
                        .title("Captain America"));
            }
        });


        return rootView;
    }

    private BitmapDescriptor bitmapDescriptorFromVector(Context context, int vectorResId) {
        Drawable vectorDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, vectorResId);
        vectorDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, vectorDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), vectorDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight());
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(vectorDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), vectorDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        vectorDrawable.draw(canvas);
        return BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap);
    }
}
```

As suggested by the comments, this is my full logcat:

```
9390-19390/? I/m.example.binf: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
2019-10-17 07:42:51.772 19390-19390/? W/m.example.binf: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
2019-10-17 07:42:52.292 19390-19390/com.example.binfo I/m.example.binf: The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
2019-10-17 07:42:53.768 19390-19390/com.example.binfo V/FA: Registered activity lifecycle callback
2019-10-17 07:42:53.770 19390-19390/com.example.binfo I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
2019-10-17 07:42:53.974 19390-19390/com.example.binfo V/FA: onActivityCreated
2019-10-17 07:42:54.032 19390-19390/com.example.binfo W/m.example.binf: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (light greylist, reflection)
2019-10-17 07:42:54.032 19390-19390/com.example.binfo W/m.example.binf: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (light greylist, reflection)
2019-10-17 07:42:54.206 19390-19390/com.example.binfo D/OpenGLRenderer: Skia GL Pipeline
2019-10-17 07:42:54.376 19390-19427/com.example.binfo V/FA: Collection enabled
2019-10-17 07:42:54.377 19390-19427/com.example.binfo V/FA: App package, google app id: com.example.binfo, 1:1010647557505:android:97517c54af5adf8581b480
2019-10-17 07:42:54.401 19390-19427/com.example.binfo I/FA: App measurement is starting up, version: 18202
2019-10-17 07:42:54.401 19390-19427/com.example.binfo I/FA: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
2019-10-17 07:42:54.401 19390-19427/com.example.binfo I/FA: To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
      adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.example.binfo
2019-10-17 07:42:54.401 19390-19427/com.example.binfo D/FA: Debug-level message logging enabled
2019-10-17 07:42:54.412 19390-19390/com.example.binfo I/zzbz: Making Creator dynamically
2019-10-17 07:42:54.422 19390-19390/com.example.binfo W/m.example.binf: Unsupported class loader
2019-10-17 07:42:54.426 19390-19390/com.example.binfo W/m.example.binf: Skipping duplicate class check due to unsupported classloader
2019-10-17 07:42:54.429 19390-19390/com.example.binfo I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.maps_dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.maps_dynamite:221
2019-10-17 07:42:54.429 19390-19390/com.example.binfo I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.maps_dynamite, version >= 221
2019-10-17 07:42:54.429 19390-19390/com.example.binfo V/DynamiteModule: Dynamite loader version >= 2, using loadModule2NoCrashUtils
2019-10-17 07:42:54.429 19390-19430/com.example.binfo W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for providerinstaller not found.
2019-10-17 07:42:54.462 19390-19390/com.example.binfo W/m.example.binf: Unsupported class loader
2019-10-17 07:42:54.464 19390-19430/com.example.binfo I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module providerinstaller:0 and remote module providerinstaller:0
2019-10-17 07:42:54.466 19390-19430/com.example.binfo W/ProviderInstaller: Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
2019-10-17 07:42:54.503 19390-19390/com.example.binfo W/m.example.binf: Skipping duplicate class check due to unsupported classloader
2019-10-17 07:42:54.539 19390-19430/com.example.binfo I/m.example.binf: The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
2019-10-17 07:42:54.553 19390-19390/com.example.binfo I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play services client version: 12451000
2019-10-17 07:42:54.556 19390-19430/com.example.binfo I/m.example.binf: The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
2019-10-17 07:42:54.557 19390-19430/com.example.binfo I/m.example.binf: The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
2019-10-17 07:42:54.567 19390-19390/com.example.binfo I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play services package version: 19420040
2019-10-17 07:42:54.580 19390-19429/com.example.binfo W/m.example.binf: Accessing hidden field Ljava/nio/Buffer;->address:J (light greylist, reflection)
2019-10-17 07:42:54.695 19390-19430/com.example.binfo V/NativeCrypto: Registering com/google/android/gms/org/conscrypt/NativeCrypto's 284 native methods...
2019-10-17 07:42:54.716 19390-19427/com.example.binfo V/FA: Connecting to remote service
2019-10-17 07:42:54.723 19390-19403/com.example.binfo I/m.example.binf: Background concurrent copying GC freed 8422(977KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 50% free, 2MB/4MB, paused 865us total 114.508ms
2019-10-17 07:42:54.805 19390-19430/com.example.binfo W/m.example.binf: Accessing hidden method Ljava/security/spec/ECParameterSpec;->getCurveName()Ljava/lang/String; (light greylist, reflection)
2019-10-17 07:42:54.811 19390-19427/com.example.binfo V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
2019-10-17 07:42:54.914 19390-19430/com.example.binfo D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
2019-10-17 07:42:54.920 19390-19430/com.example.binfo I/ProviderInstaller: Installed default security provider GmsCore_OpenSSL
2019-10-17 07:42:55.027 19390-19427/com.example.binfo V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 29685848
2019-10-17 07:42:55.055 19390-19427/com.example.binfo I/FA: Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used
2019-10-17 07:42:55.087 19390-19427/com.example.binfo D/FA: Logging event (FE): screen_view(_vs), Bundle[{ga_event_origin(_o)=auto, ga_screen_class(_sc)=MainActivity, ga_screen_id(_si)=-3010706966078322650}]
2019-10-17 07:42:55.149 19390-19459/com.example.binfo I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorDisplay retrieved: 0
2019-10-17 07:42:55.149 19390-19459/com.example.binfo I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasHDRDisplay retrieved: 0
2019-10-17 07:42:55.149 19390-19459/com.example.binfo I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
2019-10-17 07:42:55.149 19390-19459/com.example.binfo D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
2019-10-17 07:42:55.150 19390-19459/com.example.binfo W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
2019-10-17 07:42:55.150 19390-19459/com.example.binfo D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
2019-10-17 07:42:55.160 19390-19459/com.example.binfo D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xf0b09560: maj 3 min 0 rcv 3
2019-10-17 07:42:55.177 19390-19459/com.example.binfo D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xf0b09560: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xf0b31b20)
2019-10-17 07:42:55.441 19390-19459/com.example.binfo D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xf0b09560: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xf0b31b20)
2019-10-17 07:42:55.449 19390-19456/com.example.binfo D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xec3062c0: maj 1 min 0 rcv 1
2019-10-17 07:42:55.477 19390-19427/com.example.binfo V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
2019-10-17 07:42:55.493 19390-19456/com.example.binfo D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xec3062c0: ver 1 0 (tinfo 0xec303970)
2019-10-17 07:42:55.547 19390-19427/com.example.binfo V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
2019-10-17 07:42:55.626 19390-19427/com.example.binfo D/FA: Connected to remote service
2019-10-17 07:42:55.634 19390-19427/com.example.binfo V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 4
2019-10-17 07:42:57.022 19390-19457/com.example.binfo W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates not found.
2019-10-17 07:42:57.030 19390-19457/com.example.binfo I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:4
2019-10-17 07:42:57.031 19390-19457/com.example.binfo I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates, version >= 4
2019-10-17 07:42:57.035 19390-19457/com.example.binfo W/m.example.binf: Unsupported class loader
2019-10-17 07:42:57.036 19390-19457/com.example.binfo W/m.example.binf: Skipping duplicate class check due to unsupported classloader
2019-10-17 07:43:01.081 19390-19427/com.example.binfo V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
2019-10-17 07:44:30.231 19390-19474/com.example.binfo W/ManagedChannelImpl: [{0}] Failed to resolve name. status={1}
```

Comment: You got some warning or some error in logcat. can you please share it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to put Google Maps V2 on a Fragment using ViewPager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19353255/how-to-put-google-maps-v2-on-a-fragment-using-viewpager)

Comment: Hi @AkshayRaiyani the only thing that seems like an error in the logcat is this: `2019-10-17 07:55:00.468 19390-19474/com.example.binfo W/ManagedChannelImpl: [{0}] Failed to resolve name. status={1}` There is no error when I filter by tag: `map`

Comment: Oh wait I'm going to edit my post to include the full logcat @AkshayRaiyani

Comment: As per your screen shot, looks like your internet connection is missed, So can you please check it first :P

Comment: check google play console and verify that google maps is enabled and you are using correct key.https://support.google.com/googleapi/answer/6158841?hl=en

Comment: @AkshayRaiyani yes you're right, it seems there is a problem with the simulator to connect to the wifi, I'm trying to fix it

Comment: @AkshayRaiyani I fixed the problem: I just switched to another wifi connection and it worked well. If you want you can put your comment as an answer! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your code, there is no mistake I find out, but as per your screenshot, It looks like your internet connection is missed, So can you please with a proper internet connection and check it first.

Answer (score 1):

In your fragment use MapView:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".HomeFragment">

    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/llSelectDetails" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

In your fragment use:

```
  public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private MapView mMapView;

    @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)

             /*
             * Configure Mapview and sync to google map.
             */
            mMapView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.mapView);
            mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            mMapView.getMapAsync(this);
            mMapView.onResume(); // needed to get the map to display immediately

             //your code
            return rootView;
    }

    @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
            this.mMap = googleMap;
        }
    }
```

It will work fine.
Also, check your map key and internet connection.