# Google Maps crash on Android application

Tags: android, kotlin, google-maps, crash, crashlytics

I'm currently experiencing an issue with my Android application which uses Google Maps. The problem seems to be a frequent crash when attempting to launch the Google Maps inside my Fragment.

Here is a brief overview of my setup:

- Google Maps SDK version: **18.1.0**
- Target SDK version: **33**
- Minimum SDK version: **21**

Also, here are a screenshots from Crashlytics showing the crash logs: 
[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/16zlz.png) 
[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pG3rg.png)

The problem occurs mainly on Android 11 and Android 13, but I couldn't reproduce it on my device as it works fine there.

Inside XML file I'm using `FragmentContainerView` to show the map:

```
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    ...
 />
```

I have `MapFragment` that is just a standard `Fragment` that implements `OnMapReadyCallback` with `onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap)` method.

Has anyone encountered this issue before or does anyone have suggestions for potential solutions to this problem?

Comment: Have you checked out following answer already?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19353255/how-to-put-google-maps-v2-on-a-fragment-using-viewpager/19354359#19354359

Comment: Have you [filed a bug](https://developers.google.com/maps/support#issue_tracker) regarding this in the Google Issue Tracker?